# Frustrating errors (object-oriented programming)

Tags: c#

Stumbled onto a few errors coding an assignment i have, cant seem to solve. Anyone have an idea?

I've been receiving

> Error CS1061  'clsCustomer' does not contain a definition for 'Street'
>   and no extension method 'Street' accepting a first argument of type
>   'clsCustomer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS1729  'clsCustomer' does not contain a constructor that takes 5
>   arguments.
>
> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'strState' of 'clsOrder.clsOrder(string,
>   string, string, string, string, int, decimal)'

Here is the code

```
class clsOrder
{
    //declare class variables include shared (static)
    protected string cstrName;
    protected string cstrStreet;
    protected string cstrCity;
    protected string cstrState;
    protected string cstrZip;

    protected int cintQuantity;
    protected decimal cdecPrice;


    protected static decimal cdecExtendedPrice;
    protected static int cintTotalCount;
    protected static decimal cdecTotalPrice;



//declare constructors
public clsOrder()
    {

    }
    public clsOrder(string strName, string strStreet, string strCity, string strState, string strZip, int intQuantity, decimal decPrice)
    {
        this.Name = strName;
        this.Street = strStreet;
        this.City = strCity;
        this.State = strState;
        this.Zip = strZip;
        this.Quantity = intQuantity;
        this.Price = decPrice;
    }


//declare property methods
public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return cstrName;
        }
        set
        {
            cstrName = value;
        }
    }

    public string Street
    {
        get
        {
            return cstrStreet;
        }
        set
        {
            cstrStreet = value;
        }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return cstrCity;
        }
        set
        {
            cstrCity = value;
        }
    }

    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return cstrState;
        }
        set
        {
            cstrState = value;
        }
    }

    public string Zip
    {
        get
        {
            return cstrZip;
        }
        set
        {
            cstrZip = value;
        }
    }

    public int Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return cintQuantity;
        }
        set
        {
            cintQuantity = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return cdecPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            cdecPrice = value;
        }
    }
```

and Here is where I'm getting the Errors

```
clsCustomer cobjCustomer = new clsCustomer(txtName.Text, txtStreet.Text,
                    txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtZip.Text); //Here

strMailingLabel = cobjCustomer.Name + "\n" +     //Here     
                  cobjCustomer.Street + "\n" +    //Here
                  cobjCustomer.City + ", " +     //Here
                  cobjCustomer.State + "  " + cobjCustomer.Zip;    //Here

lblMailingLabel.Text = strMailingLabel;

clsOrder cobjOrder = new clsOrder  //Here
    (txtDescription.Text,
     int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text),
     decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text));
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code with your question but it's totally college time again. :)

Comment: I'm stuck as can be, made a mistake and took this class online. You're my only hope Obi-wan

Comment: Order constructor expects 7 parameters. You are passing only 3. For customere you have not provided code...

Comment: So i just realized i wrote what was suppose to be in Customer in Order. Im going to step back and rewrite it. Thanks for all the support. Ill update once im finished.

Comment: Did you mean for clsOrder to be nested in clsCustomer? Some ntes on style: Rather mark the access modifier explicitly on clsCustomer (probably should be public). You already have to put 'class' before a class... "cls" seems redundant. Usually class names start with a capital.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a class with name `clsOrder`
And you creating an instance of class `clsCustomer`

Change accordingly:

```
clsOrder cobjCustomer = new clsOrder(txtName.Text, txtStreet.Text,
                                txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtZip.Text); //Here


            strMailingLabel = cobjCustomer.Name + "\n" +     //Here     
                              cobjCustomer.Street + "\n" +    //Here
                              cobjCustomer.City + ", " +     //Here
                              cobjCustomer.State + "  " + cobjCustomer.Zip;    //Here


            lblMailingLabel.Text = strMailingLabel;


            clsOrder cobjOrder = new clsOrder  //Here
                (txtDescription.Text,
                 int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text),
                 decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text));
```

And you need to declare last two parameters as optional if they are not important :

```
public clsOrder(string strName, string strStreet, string strCity, string strState, 
                string strZip, int intQuantity = 0, decimal decPrice = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor signature, you're declaring that you expect `int intQuantity, decimal decPrice`, but you're only providing the address fields. If you want quantity and price to be optional, you need to provide default values:

```
public clsOrder(string strName, string strStreet, string strCity, string strState, 
                string strZip, int intQuantity = 0, decimal decPrice = 0)
```

Also, you've shown us the code for `clsOrder`, so I suppose that's what you want to instantiate, not `clsCustomer`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one your constructor takes 7 parameters and you are passing 5.

You have set your constructor up to take 7 arguments but are passing 5 hence and error about passing 5 parameters and not 7.

Now if the last two are not required you can use optional parameters. Meaning if you don't provide them they default to a value.

```
public clsOrder(string strName, string strStreet, string strCity, string strState, string strZip, int intQuantity, decimal decPrice)
    {
        this.Name = strName;
        this.Street = strStreet;
        this.City = strCity;
        this.State = strState;
        this.Zip = strZip;
        this.Quantity = intQuantity;
        this.Price = decPrice;
    }
```

Should be:

```
 public clsOrder(string strName, string strStreet, string strCity, string strState, string strZip, int Quantity = 0, decimal decPrice = 0.0)
    {
        this.Name = strName;
        this.Street = strStreet;
        this.City = strCity;
        this.State = strState;
        this.Zip = strZip;
        this.Quantity = intQuantity;
        this.Price = decPrice;
    }
```